# Transforming the Bounds of an Integral for the Change of Variables Theorem

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

For a homework problem, I'm supposed to compute $$\iint_R(x+y)\,dy\,dx$$ over the region $R = \{(x,y) \,|\, (0 \le x \le 1) \, \land (0 \le y \le x)\}$ using the transfomation $T(x,y) = (u+v,u-v)$.  I know that the result of applying the change of variables theorem is $$\iint_{T(R)}2u\left|\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}\right|\,dv\,du = \iint_{T(R)}4u\,dv\,du,$$ but I'm not completely sure how to go about computing the bounds of the integral (i.e. $T(R)$).  How do I find appropriate bounds for $u$ and $v$ so I can compute this as an iterated integral?

Comment: Is $\iint_{T(R)}2u\left|\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}\right|\,dy\,dx $ not $\iint_{T(R)}2u\left|\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}\right|\,du\,dv $?

Comment: Yes, my bad.  Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $x=u+v$ and $y=u-v$
$$T(R)=\left\{(u,v):0\le u+v\le1\ \land \ 0\le u-v\le u+v\right\}.$$
From $0\le u+v$ we get $$\color{red}{-u\le v}. \tag 1$$
From $u+v\le1$ we get 
$$\color{blue}{v\le -u+1}. \tag 2$$
From $0\le u-v$ $$\color{green}{v\le u}. \tag 3$$
From $u-v\le u+v$ we get that $$\color{brown}{v\ge 0}. \tag 4$$

The figure below depicts the intersection of the red, blue, green, and brown region (gray).

[image]

In other words,

$$T(R)=\left\{(u,v):\color{red}{-u\le v}\land\color{blue}{v\le -u+1}\land\color{green}{v\le u}\land\color{brown}{v\ge 0}\right\}.$$

---

Regarding the above given expression of $T(R)$, the transformed integral we have is:

$$\iint_{T(R)}4u\ dv \ du=\int_0^{\frac12}\left[\int_{\color{brown}0}^{\color{green}u} 4u\  dv\right]\ du+\int_{\frac12}^1 \left[\int_{\color{brown}0}^{\color{blue}{-u+1}}4u\ dv \right]\ du=\frac12.$$

Just like the original integral which is

$$\iint_R x+y \ dxdy=\int_0^1 \left[\int_0^x x+y \ dy \right]\ dx=\frac12.$$

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how did you get the graph?  From a website?

Comment: @AaronHall: From a website? Duellum! The website I am; I love drawing.

Comment: Cool.  You did a great job!